# How can I mollify the compiler re: returning the result within a try block?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception, try-catch

I have code like this:

```
try {
    if (!(oc.State == ConnectionState.Open)) {
        oc.Open();
    }
    query = "SELECT DUCKBILL FROM PLATYPUS";
    da = new OracleDataAdapter();
    oCommand = new OracleCommand(query, oc);
    oCommand.Parameters.Add("ABCid", platypusABCID);
    da.SelectCommand = oCommand;
    dt = new OracleDataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
} catch (OracleException e) {
    log.Error(e, e);
    //return dt; //use of unassigned local variable 'dt'
}
//return dt; //use of unassigned local variable 'dt'
```

...which stops me with either *"not all code paths return a value"* or (as commented) *"use of unassigned local variable 'dt'"*

I can get rid of the try..catch, but as this is a database operation, I'd like to be able to log any resultant err msg. How can I keep my exception handling and also appease the grouch? I know, it's a benevolent grouch, but still...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preassign it with a new table or null;

```
OracleDataTable dt = null;
```

OR

```
var dt = new OracleDataTable();
```

And then:

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch
{
    ...
}

return dt; // Will return null.
```

If you assign it with a new table, it will return an empty table in case of an exception.

Choose which one you prefer logically, considering your situation.

Comment: `var dt = null` won't work, as you can't implicitly type a variable and assign it to null, you'll have to specify the type.

Comment: It works, actually. And I only added "actually" because "It works" was too short a comment. Oh, "var" doesn't work...okay, sorry. My way works, though (OracleTable dt = null)

Comment: Ah yeah that way will work, but var won't, var works on determining the type via from what's after the equals sign, but null isn't a type :)

Comment: Sorry about the `var`, wasn't writing in VS and I'm used to typing var.

Comment: Depending on the implementation of `OracleDataAdapter`'s `Fill` method, this solution *might* result in a partly-filled `OracleDataTable` being returned. Are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 2):

I'd just rethrow the exception:

```
} catch (OracleException e) {
    log.Error(e, e);
    throw;
}
```

It's usually better to let the exception bubble up, as it's very unlikely that merely logging the exception is sufficient for the exception to actually be "handled" (and allow the program flow to continue merrily without any problems).

Comment: explicitly throwing (or re-throwing) an exception is just the same as returning a value when it comes to the compiler determining "do all code paths return a value".  That is why this solution works.

Comment: Log-and-throw is an anti-pattern. It produces several log entries for one error.

Comment: I agree, I wouldn't log it either since I'd leave that to a global handler.  I was trying to address the fact that other answerers were suggesting that the OP return null, which is far worse.

Answer (score 1):

Just set it to a new table, then return it in the `finally` block as this gets executed regardless of whether the exception was thrown or not.

```
OracleDataTable dt = new OracleDataTable();

try
{
    //your code
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
    //your code
}
finally
{
    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather go with wrapping your database exception with exception, which has more value for calling code:

```
try {
    if (!(oc.State == ConnectionState.Open)) {
        oc.Open();
    }
    query = "SELECT DUCKBILL FROM PLATYPUS";
    da = new OracleDataAdapter();
    oCommand = new OracleCommand(query, oc);
    oCommand.Parameters.Add("ABCid", platypusABCID);
    da.SelectCommand = oCommand;
    dt = new OracleDataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
} catch (OracleException e) {
    throw new MyDataLayerException("Cannot retrieve duckbill", e);   
}
```

In this case your calling code will not be forced to check returned value for `null`, and in case of exception, you will log it once upper in stack with all context information.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is quite obviously correct in complaining that "not all code paths return a value". A non-`void` method needs to either (a) return a value, or (b) throw an exception.

Your code currently does neither when the DB operation fails: You are catching the exception, but you're neither re-throwing it to the caller, nor are you returning a value from inside the `catch` block.

**What should your method return in the case of an error condition?**

*You* have to decide this. Noone can tell you *the* correct answer, because there are many sensible solutions. For example:

- Should it return `null`?

  If so, `return null;` from inside the `catch` block, after you've logged the error.
- Should it return an empty table?

  Then `return new OracleDataTable();` from inside the `catch` block.
- Or, perhaps, should it return nothing at all?

  Then re-`throw;` the exception inside the catch block, after you've logged it.

(It might help to clearly define the contract of your method, e.g. think about what kinds of guarantees your method makes to the calling code.)